# Nicedit editor image upload

Tags: javascript, nicedit

i am using "niceEdit" editor in my website anyhow it was working charm but now i get this massage when i trying to "upload" an image to the editor.

**"There was an error uploading your image (Sending your image to imageshack failed."**

i look for it and found that someone has change with niceuplod file and you must also get api key .

so i change my way in calling the editor from the following :

```
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() { 
           nicEditors.allTextAreas(new nicEditor({maxHeight : 250}).panelInstance('contect'));

         });

        $('form').submit(function(){
nicEditors.findEditor('contect').saveContent();
//console.log(nicEditors.findEditor('contect').getContent());

        });



to this one 
bkLib.onDomLoaded(function() {
    new nicEditor({
        buttonList : ['bold','italic','underline','upload'],
        iconsPath:'nicEditorIcons.gif',
        uploadURI : 'nicUpload.php', 
    }).panelInstance('contect');
});

then i got the following error 
top.nicUploadButton is undefined
and in my console the following 
TypeError: r.removeInstance is not a function

r.removeInstance(e);
```

So why do you think am having this issue , am from where should i start looking ?

Answer (score 0):

you must have your own API code from the website 
and then change it in your niceUpload file

you will fine it in the beginning of the code

Answer (score 0):

http://wiki.nicedit.com/w/page/515/Configuration%20Options

Look for uploadURI option, it will work for you, same worked for me too.